# How can I ask for a float input and an integer at the same time?

Tags: python, input, integer

I want to ask subjects to type in first a float number ( like 3.666) followed by an integer.
what i did is:

```
x,y = input ( " Please enter two numbers"). split ()
```

and then converted

```
x,y =[ float (x), int (y)]
```

It does not work-are there any suggestions?

Comment: You should use raw_input(). The difference between them is that "input()" scans the input as a number while "raw_input()" scans it like a string .

Comment: Scanning a number and splitting it by a space doesn't makes sense. Hope you understand.

Comment: and next time you post question, please add language name in the tags :)

Comment: I will! Thanks so much for your help!!!!!

Comment: input is ok if Laurie is using python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to scan them as a string, separate it by space as delimiter and then typecast them to their corresponding types.

```
s = raw_input("Please enter two numbers: ")
x,y = s.split(" ")
x = float(x)
y = int(y)
```

Hope that helps :)